# What is the calling convention difference between LAPACKE_zgetrf() and zgetrf_() in OpenBLAS?

Tags: lapack, blas, openblas, atlas, lapacke

I'm trying to support zgetrf() in both Ubuntu 18.04 and CentOS 7 by using dlopen() against the .so and opening the function in each version, but the calling convention is different.  In CentOS it works using LAPACKE_zgetrf() but in Ubuntu 18.04 they do not export as LAPACKE_zgetrf, the only option is zgetrf_:

```
# objdump -T /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0 |grep zgetrf
[...]
000c3a60 g    DF .text  00000191  Base        zgetrf_
```

I can make an LAPACKE_zgetrf() call as follows, this works:

```
LAPACKE_zgetrf(order, m, n, a, ndim, (int32_t*)ip);
```

How do I convert it to call `zgetrf_(...)` ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69276806/14055985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LAPACKE_ functions will call the linked openblas.so.0 library, so no need to link to openblas.so.0 directly.

For ATLAS, you can call the clapack_ functions exported by liblapack_atlas.so.3 which are nearly the same format (same order, same type) except that the `transform` argument is different.  For example, in `zgetrs()` in ATLAS might take the standard BLAS `CblasTrans` enum for the `transform` argument.  However, in OpenBLAS (and MKL) this argument should be converted from ATLAS to OpenBLAS as follows:

`openblas_trans = ((trans) == CblasConjTrans ? 'C' : ((trans) == CblasTrans ? 'T' : 'N'))`