# How do libatlas3, liblapacke, and libopenblas0 interact with eachother?

Tags: lapack, blas, openblas, atlas, lapacke

I'm trying to figure out the interaction between the following library packages in Debian 11 and Ubuntu 20.04:

- libatlas3-base
- liblapacke
- OpenBLAS

  - libopenblas0-openmp
  - libopenblas0-pthread
  - libopenblas0-serial

It looks like the OpenBLAS packages can only be used one at a time because they are in different subdirs shown here.  How do I select the active one?

- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-openmp/libopenblas.so.0
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblas.so.0
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-serial/libopenblas.so.0

Once I've selected the active OpenBLAS implementation, will libatlas3 or liblapacke use the active implementation?  How can you tell what they are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Libraries are selected with alternatives:

  - `~# update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu`
  - `~# update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu`
- liblapacke.so.3 will use whichever pair of liblapack.so.3 and libblas.so.3 libraries are currently selected from above.
- libatlas3-base provides liblapack_atlas.so.3 which will always use the ATLAS implementation.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318554/why-are-there-so-many-openblas-packages-and-which-one-would-yield-fastest-result/1365052#1365052